# Bind two Entity without intermediate Entity spring data jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a user table(and entity)

```
create table users(
  id                              number(9)          not null,
  alias                           varchar2(200 char),
  name_en                         varchar2(200 char),
  state                           varchar2(1)        not null
);
```

and user groups

```
create table user_groups(
  group_id                        number(9)          not null,
  alias                           varchar2(200)      not null,
  name_en                         varchar2(200 char),
  state                           varchar2(1)        not null,
  constraint user_groups1 primary key (group_id)
);
```

group users are stored in bind table

```
create table user_group_binds(
  group_id                        number(9)          not null,
  user_id                         number(9)          not null,
  constraint user_group_binds1 foreign key (group_id) references user_groups(group_id),
  constraint user_group_binds2 foreign key (user_id) references users(id)
);
```

I want to have in my group entity list of userEntity(without bind entity). Any ideas?
Of course, I can use @Query annotation, but I have other entities who mapped with group and they will automatic get group entity.
Can I override automatical methods?

Comment: You would have to use `@JoinTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@JoinTable` and define column mapping with join table in `UserGroup` Enitity

```
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(name = "user_group_binds",
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "group_id", referencedColumnName = "group_id")},
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
  List<UserEntity> users;
```